# Difference between os.stat(PATH).st_atime and os.path.getatime(PATH))

Tags: python

I've been seeing `os.stat(PATH).st_atime` and `os.path.getatime(PATH)` used interchangeably. The same is valid for `st_mtime` and `getmtime`, as well as `st_ctime` and `getctime`.

When testing on several different paths, the two return the same epoch time.

Looking through the documentation for [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) and [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=getatime#os.path.getatime) didn't clarify the difference between the two.

Are there any practical differences ? In what cases should I use one or the other ?

Comment: They get the same value, but `os.stat()` has a few more options and is a bit more flexible. You probably pay a small overhead for that in execution time, but I'd expect that to be very small compared to the time actually required to obtain the atime. You could write a test with `timeit` to see if there's a noticable and substantial difference, but normally I'd prefer `os.stat` - although I use `Path.stat` from `pathlib` when performance isn't absolutely key, for even greater convenience and readable code.